# How do I count button clicks for a certain user and then display the count?

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

My question is how I could be able to save the count of clicks to MySQL table and then on a different page show how many times they have clicked the button?

I'm creating a web application to count how many times a user has pressed a button. Every time the user logs in they should be able to see the click count on a different page.

Page usermenu.php

```
<a href="lisakohv.php">
  <span>Add Coffee!</span>
</a>
```

Page statistics.php

```
<div align="center" class="col-lg-3 stats">
   <i class="fa fa-coffee" aria-hidden="true"></i>
   <div class="counting" data-count="999">0</div>
   <h5>Cups of coffee</h5>
</div>
```

I expect that the count of clicks is 5 and then saves the number to a MySQL table and then displays the number 5 to statistics.php.

Comment: What's on `lisakohv.php`? This is where you would update the records in the database.

Comment: Update on `lisakohv.php`, on `statistics.php` select the record for the relevant row, or all records. You probably want an `id` on the link as well. `<a href="lisakohv.php?id=someid">`

Comment: Do you have any php code to share? Either in lisakohv.php or statistics.php

Comment: We would also need to know more about your table structure and how your application is tracking and discerning users. At the moment all you have provided us with is a few non-descriptive html snippets. It appears that you're asking for a tutorial on how to track user activity throughout your application, more so than addressing a specific problem with doing so. Please see [What topics can I ask about here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You cant with just PHP**

Because PHP is a backend language, you won't be able to see what your users are doing. When a user clicks on your link for lisakohv.php it makes a request to your server. Then the server will do any work that it needs to do and send the page back to the user. Once it sends the information it's work is done, and it wait for the next request to come in.

Edit: On second thought its totally possible with straight PHP. At the top of your file just call a function that will insert the username and file name into the database when it loads. IE:

```
get the user name and link name
open DB connection
build query
insert into database
```

But i would recommend using the Ajax method bellow.

**You can use Javascript and PHP though**

You may want to look into creating a REST based API in PHP and writing a simple javascript script that will call the API every time a user clicks. Using a API and Javascript to talk to your server is commonly called [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/whatis/whatis_ajax.asp). Then you can use your database to fill out a page that shows the user how many clicks they've done.

Comment: YOU ARE A GENIUS. Thanks a lot. This might even work now